# Will putting functions in one file improve speed?

Tags: r, performance, function, file

If I write all my functions into one file that I use for multiple scripts, will sourcing the file containing the functions once at the top of my script improve my speed? If I call source(fn.r) for example, will I be able to call the functions I created as they are already saved in the workspace? I am trying to reduce the time it takes for the script to run and improve performance. Any other tips regarding improving speed are welcome aswell

Comment: If you have a lot of functions to source, you might want to consider bundling them into a package. I doubt there is much difference in speed, but thereally is a simplicity to loading a package to be gained. I doubt that sourcing one file over several will make much difference. If you're sourcing so many files that you gain any performance boost by putting them in one gile, I would guess you're well into the thousands of files.

Answer (score 0):

Sourcing the file loads any functions within that script. Sourcing doesn't have much impact on the speed at which those functions run, as they would be in memory regardless, but you should look at the R compiler for an easy way to get a moderate speed boost.

See this [blog post](https://www.r-statistics.com/2012/04/speed-up-your-r-code-using-a-just-in-time-jit-compiler/) about the compiler

> the performance gain for various made-up functions can range between
>   2x to 5x times faster running time.  This is great for the small
>   amount of work ... it requires ...  Moreover, by combining
>   C/C++ code with R code (through the {Rcpp} and {Inline} packages) you
>   can improve your code’s running time by a factor of 80 ... relative to
>   interpreted code.  But to be fair to R, the code that is used for such
>   examples is often unrealistic code examples that is often not
>   representative of real R work. Thus, effective speed gains can be
>   expected to be smaller.

The easiest way to use the compiler is to place this at the beginning of your script. R will then automatically compile any function you create.

```
require(compiler)
enableJIT(3)
```